# Is there any way to have key_name and id at the same time for GAE datastore entity?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In addition to the `key_name` I generate, I also would like to have some other property, which will act as id (I don't want to show `key_name` to the user). Can it be `id`? Or, how to generate unique value instead of `id`?

What I will do - I will generate a url with usage of that id and parent key name. If user clicks on this link, I'll need to find this datastore entity and update it.

Here is the current code.

Creation of the record:

```
  item = Items.get_by_key_name(key_names=user_id, parent=person)
  if item is None:
    item = Items(key_name='id'+user_id, parent=person)
```

Getting the record:

```
item = Items.get_by_key_name(key_names=user_id, parent=person)
```

`user_id` is what should be hidden.

Comment: can't you use directly the base64 encoded key?

Comment: @systempuntoout, without keeping that in datastore? I'll need to identify according datastore entity later on with usage of this id.

Comment: yes, just use directly the key (base64 encoded) and not the key_name

Comment: Ah, you are suggesting to replace my current value of `key_name` with `key_name=md5(key_name).hexdigest()`? Looks like good approach ;). The only problem I see is that `key_name` should be started with letter (not digit), but I can always add some dummy letter at the beginning. Please post that as answer, so I'll accept it.

Comment: not exactly, could you please add the snippet of code where you get the key_name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be probably wrong because your requirements are not clear, but for me you should pass just the key to the view using:

```
item.key()
```

then you could pass back the key to the controller and easily retrieve a given entity with:

```
item = Items.get(key)
```

Comment: Can I use this key() value in URL?

Comment: Yes it is safe, Gae uses a modified Base64 for URL that is perfect for this purpose.

Comment: Can't I just decode the Base64 to get back the original username?  that doesn't seem very secure.  Or are you still planning on doing something with md5?

Comment: How this key is generated by GAE? I thought that this is random value.

Answer (score 3):

Entities have exactly one of a key name or ID - never both. You could create an entity with a single ReferenceProperty pointing to your target entity, and use its ID as an identifier, but there really should be no reason not to reveal a key name to a user - a well authored app should not rely on this value remaining secret.

Note that it's trivially easy to extract the key name (and the rest of the information about a key) from the string encoded key.

Comment: Nick, what if instead of `key_name='id'+user_id` I'll use for ex., `key_name='constant'+md5('id'+user_id+'-'+parent.key().name()).hexdigest()`?

Comment: Can I define `id` myself (it will be numeric)? Or, should I use `key_name` instead?

Comment: @LA_ Yes, you could do that, but there's still no point in doing so (and even less point in including the parent key name in it). You can define your own ID, but if you ever forget to do so, autogenerated IDs will be used, potentially overwriting your own entities. Your best approach is still to use the existing key name, rather than trying to obfuscate it.